# Do every user defined Class in java has a class Class object associated with it ? Then how it is different from Reflection?

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

Not able to understand `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()`. What is `.class` here? Is it a reference of `class` Class ?

Then what is the difference in getting `ClassLoader` info using reflection ?

Comment: Each class has an associated unique object of class `Class` which represents it. That object may be accessed using `.class` and other means. `.class` is part of the reflection mechanism.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Thanks for clarification ... but I still have a doubt  how it is associated  How can I see it ...like we can see all the object class methods in our classes ?

Comment: Not idea what you mean by seeing it. For each class loaded the JVM creates a unique object of class `Class`. And, when compiling `.class`, the compiler generates bytecode to get the reference of such object which will have been created by the JVM.

Comment: It *isn't* different. You don't get Reflection information from the `ClassLoader,` or *vice versa* either. You get it from the `Class.`

Comment: I think after .class file is loaded then only JVM creates class Class Object . And Yes there is only one class Class object is created for any insatnces of that class(Myclass) ... what I am trying to understand is that how class Class object gets associated and when it gets associated

Comment: Thanks I got the answer ... I got somewhat confused ... MyClass.class returns instance of Class<MyClass> ... I thought that class is some field  member so i was searching in which class it will be .

Answer (score 2):

> Does every user defined Class in java have a `Class` object associated with it ?

Yes.  And every system defined class too.  (Though the `Class` object may not be created until you attempt to get its reference.)

> Not able to understand `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()`. What is `.class` here? Is it a reference of class Class ?

Yes.  Or more precisely, it is a reference of type `Class<MyClass>`.  It refers to the one (and only) `Class` object that corresponds to the type.

---

> Then what is the difference in getting ClassLoader info using reflection ?

There are three differences between

```
    MyClass.class
```

and

```
   String someClassName = ...

   classloader.getClass(someClassName)
```

or

```
   Class.forName(someClassName)
```

In the first case the, class name is hardwired into your code, but the expression will always work<sup>1</sup>, and the type of the class object you get is known at compile time to be `Class<MyClass>`.

In the second and third (equivalent) cases, the class name can be a runtime variable, but the expression could fail (because the named class does not exist for example) and the type is only known at compile time to be `Class<?>`.

However, assuming that things work, the information you get (i.e. the `Class` object) is identical in all three cases.

---

<sup>1 - That is possibly an overstatement.  However the scenarios where you might see an exception there involve JVMs in error states. You would have to something pretty bad to see them, like catching recovering from a previous `ExceptionInInitializerError` or a `NoClassDefFoundError`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ... .. what I am trying to understand is that how class Class object gets associated and when it get associated i mean which phase .Below is my understanding :                                   1) once .class file is loaded JVM creates an instance of class Class which contains details of MyClass.class .                                                      Till this point i am clear . Now if . Now not able to understand this MyClass.class.getClassLoader()

Comment: What are you unable to understand about it?  Have you read the javadoc for the `Class.getClassLoader()` method?

Comment: I asked class Class Object not about Object class                                Does every user defined Class in java have a class Class object associated with it not Object Class .

Comment: Thanks I got the answer ... I got somewhat confused ... MyClass.class returns instance of Class<MyClass> ... I thought that class is some field  member so i was searching in which class it will be .

Comment: Answer: Yes.  That's what I said above.  I did not mention the class `Object` (i.e. `java.lang.Object`) at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you write .class after a class name, it references the Class object that represents the given class.

For example, if your class is Foo, then Foo.class is an object that represents the class Foo on runtime.
It is the same object that is returned by the getClass() method of any (direct) instance of Foo.

```
Foo bar = new Foo ();
System.out.println(Foo.class.getName());
System.out.println(bar.getClass().getName());
```

I think the key here is understanding the difference between a Class and an Object. An Object is an instance of a Class. But in a fully object-oriented language, a Class is also an Object. So calling .class gets the reference to the Class object of that Class, which can then be manipulated.

Comment: bar.class is not accessible , It should be Foo.class

Comment: Yes, sorry (i've changed it).

Comment: Thanks I got the answer ... I got somewhat confused ... MyClass.class returns instance of Class<MyClass> ... I thought that class is some field  member so i was searching in which class it will be .